# Navlink- route not found issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Our Products

//FileName- allProducts
import React from 'react'

const AllProducts = () => {
return (
AllProducts
)
}

export default AllProducts;

I am not being redirected to this page as the output is not displayed any suggestions on how do i fix this.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the relevant routing and navigation code? See [mcve]. Also, `return ( AllProducts )` doesn't appear to be valid JSX.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are not getting output because in react, when you try to return a component, it wont automatically render its content unless you use it as a JSX element in another component rendering part.

Try to render any JSX code in the return statement instead of component itself.

```
// FileName - allProducts.js
import React from 'react';

const AllProducts = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>All Products</h1>
      {/* Add any other JSX content here that you want to print*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllProducts;
```